# How can i loop through this dict and grab the data i want based on value?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, dictionary

Hi i have a json variable which i grabbed from requests and i want to loop through the items to get the items i want based on the key and value eg:
select row from data where key="abc" and value=True
But i also want to get the id of that row so i can get the second row data
I know it is messy but i tried to explain
Please see the image below
[image: first]

[image: second]

I'm fairly new to python, after switching from nodejs "hell" i find python way easier and better, json/dict decoding is a pain but still manageable hehe
I have no idea how to accomplish this
Below is my actual code that i get from an api

```
response = requests.post('https://www.com', headers=tmp, data=data).json()
            x = json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False)
            print x['aaa']
```

The above code works to print items but i want to loop through them to get the desired data from a>id and b>id where a.is_data_real = True
Thank you

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

First transform `x['bbbb']` into a dictionary where the key is `id` and the value is the bbbb row - this makes finding the row by id faster as we don't have to iterate, we can just do a dict lookup

```
b_map = {b['id']:b for b in x['bbbb']}
```

Now you can use a comprehension to get all "a" rows where "data_is_real" is true, and add the matching row from b like this

```
[(a, b_map[a['id']]) for a in x['aaa'] if a['data_is_real']]
```

Comment: Hi again, thank you for the responses, i decided to do a for loop and managed to get the data easily, the above answers seem kinda hard lol
The code is below for reference:
`for bbbb in jclean['bbbb']:  
                if bbbb['id'] == 10 and bbbb['is_value'] == True:  
                    id = bbbb['id']  
                    for aaaa in jclean['aaaa']:  
                        if aaaa['1_id'] == id or aaaa['2_id'] == id:  
                            print aaaa['id']`

Works like a charm, between i am unable to clean russian text to work without breaking anything

Comment: this is code from requests post:
`s = response.text
            jclean = json.loads(s.encode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent correctly, the following should work for you. This was tested on Python 2.7.15rc1:

```
# Example Data
data = {"aaa":[{"etrert":619337442,"home":"werewrw","id": 595506140083,"is_data_real": True},{"etrert":719337432,"home":"filler","id": 695506149983,"is_data_real": True}, {"etrert":719337432,"home":"filler","id": 795506149983,"is_data_real": False}], "bbb":[{"roi":0,"qweqweqe":1,"id": 595506140083},{"roi":1,"qweqweqe":1,"id": 695506149983},{"roi":0,"qweqweqe":1,"id": 59550999983},{"roi":1,"qweqweqe":3,"id": 595506140083}]}

# Create a Filter Function Creator
# If it finds the id, only returns it if "is_data_real" is True
def create_id_filter(id_needed):
    def id_filter(d):
        if d["id"] == id_needed and d["is_data_real"] == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        return
    return id_filter

# Create a filter for any id number you want
id_filter = create_id_filter(595506140083)

# Filter the "aaa" objects using the filter created above
real_a = filter(id_filter, data["aaa"])

# Use list comprehension to pull out just the ids
a_ids = [x['id'] for x in real_a]

# Use list comprehension to pull all b objects that match the id
b_matches = [x for x in data["bbb"] if x["id"] in a_ids]

print b_matches
# [{'roi': 0, 'qweqweqe': 1, 'id': 595506140083}, {'roi': 1, 'qweqweqe': 3, 'id': 595506140083}]
```

Also, if you have a list of id's, you can get all results from "bbb" like so:

```
def get_b_matches(request_data, id_list):
    result = []
    for i in id_list:
        id_filter = create_id_filter(i)
        real_a = filter(id_filter, request_data["aaa"])
        a_ids = [x['id'] for x in real_a]
        b_matches = [x for x in request_data["bbb"] if x["id"] in a_ids]
        result.extend(b_matches)
    return result

get_b_matches(data, [595506140083, 695506149983])
# [{'roi': 0, 'qweqweqe': 1, 'id': 595506140083}, {'roi': 1, 'qweqweqe': 3, 'id': 595506140083}, {'roi': 1, 'qweqweqe': 1, 'id': 695506149983}]
```